# Selfish Programs

Tags: code-golf, code-challenge, quine

### The Challenge

Write two programs `P` and `Q` such that:

- `P` and `Q` are written in the same language
- The output of `P` is `Q`
- The output of `Q` is `P`
- `P` and `Q` are both non-empty

Simple enough. Surely that's been done here before. Where this gets interesting is the scoring.

### Scoring

- `P` and `Q` are selfish, they don't want to sheir their precious characters! The primary means of scoring is the number of source characters existing in both `P` and `Q`. The lower the number the better.
- If two programs share the same number of characters, the sum length of their programs will be the tie breaker.

### Clarification and Example

There's two ways to interpret this and I feel an example would best explain which is correct.

We say the programs `aabb` and `bbcc` share a single character, `b`, **NOT** two characters `b` and `b`

Comment: I think you should at least require that the two programs are nonempty. You might want to let this sit in the sandbox a while, since there are probably other things I haven't thought of that might hurt your chances at getting interesting answers.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman nice catch!

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Mutually exclusive quines](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/153948/78410). If we assume this challenge is also asking for proper quines, the winner of the linked challenge will also win here (primary score 0 and shortest length sum as the tiebreaker). If non-proper quines are allowed, P and Q should at least be distinct, otherwise the answer zone will be flooded with trivial answers like `P = Q = 1`.

Comment: @Bubbler oh wow, that was pretty much my original thought, but I though only allowing no overlap might exclude too many languages. Guess I was wrong XD